# Multiple vertical 100% height & width divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create multiple divs with 100% both width & height, but keep failing miserably. Example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="1">100% height & width, all you can see when opening this file!</div>
        <div id="2">I'll be 100% when you've scrolled #1 out of the window!</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the css for this solution? I can't seem get it working.

Comment: When you say 100% do you mean of the browser width and height?

Comment: What is your expected output? Could you upload an image or something like that?

Comment: I deleted my comment after realizing what you had was exactly what he wanted - and upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is first reset default values for `margin` and `padding`:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Second make your `html` and `body` be the 100%:

```
html, body {
   height:100%;
}
```

Then your dimension for divs:

```
#wrapper, #one, #two {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

<sub>You can't assign numeric values for id or class on the first charachter</sub>

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/3fCZg/**

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of HTML and CSS if you create 2 divs that have a width and height of 100% and place them in the same containing div, you will only see 1 of the divs because they are both the exact same height and width and are placed on top of each other.

EDIT: Sorry I was thinking of inline elements and z-index (here is the code to get what you want done, if I am reading your post correctly

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        #wrapper {
            width: 498px;
            height: 498px;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
        }

        #box1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        #box2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="box1"></div>
        <div id="box2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope that works!

EDIT: You can change the container div to be whatever height you want it to be to further customize this :D, now you can use your intuition to create what you were hoping to create!

Comment: What's the upvote for? This is only true if either `div` have been repositioned using `position`, which wasn't mentioned in this answer at all.

Comment: I edited the comment to fix it....I was thinking of something entirely different! Hopefully my answer is more up to par now.