# Filling whole browser using css

Tags: css

I am trying to fill whole browser.But it is not filling.

css:

```
body {    
  color:#00000;
  font-family:"Segoe UI Light" , sans-serif;
}

#container { 
  margin: 0px auto; 
 width:100%;
}

#header{
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#3399cc; 
}
```

here it is not filling the whole browser

Comment: Check this answer in this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433129/multiple-vertical-100-height-width-divs/20433214#20433214

Answer (score 1):

The `height` property is relative to the content, differently from `width` (that is relative to the browser dimension).

You can use the following code to achieve what you want:

```
html, body { height:100% }

body {
  color:#00000;
  font-family:"Segoe UI Light" , sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TadUr/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this: **[`jsFiddle LIVE DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/XjEYd/)**

```
html,body { 
    padding:0; margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#432332;
}
</style>

<div>selement</div>
```